# Javascript only checks one field

Tags: javascript

Ok so I've been stumped on this one for days and its frustrating me. (Will frustrate me even more if it's something simple I'm overlooking).

I have a form generated in PHP which I want to verify that certain pieces are filled out. I do this via a JavaScript check when the user clicks the submit button.The JavaScript code is below:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

        function checkFields()
        { 
            if (document.getElementById('ldescription').value == '' || document.getElementById('uname').value == '' 
                || document.getElementById('sdescription').value == '' || document.getElementById('email').value == '' 
                || document.getElementById('platf').value == "Select Group" || document.getElementByID('cate').value == "Select Category" )
            {
                alert("Please fill out all of the starred (*) items" );
                return false;
            }
        }
        </script>
```

For some reason though this only checks the **ldescription** field. If that field has text but all the others are empty it carries on like everything was filled out. Also if I change the order of my checks and **ldescription** is anywhere but the first check, it will do no check whatsoever even when all the fields are empty.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Got it fixed. Along with the suggestion I marked as correct the **document.getElementById('item').value**  command worked with only textarea boxes but not regular text input boxes. By changing the command to **document.MyForm.myTextName.value** everything fell into place.

Comment: Can you provide the html form to go along with this.  There could be names/id's that are wrong.  Nothing wrong with the code itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of problems i noticed with your sample code.

- The last `getElementById` call has improper casing.  The final `d` is capitalized and it shouldn't be
- Comparing the value to a string literal should be done by `===` not `==`.
- JSLint complains there are line break issues in your if statement by having the line begin with `||` instead of having the previous line end with `||`.

The first and third items are most likely the ones causing your problem.

Comment: Your first and third suggestions, while they did not solve the problem entirely, they were part of the problem. getElementById worked fine for textarea boxes, but not for regular text input boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your if condition, when you are breaking a line, make sure that the last token in the line is the OR operator ||.

Javascript does semicolon insertion, so it may be that semicolons are being inserted (automatically, invisibly, by the interpreter) in a bad place.

Try the below code

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function checkFields()
    { 
        if (document.getElementById('ldescription').value === '' ||
            document.getElementById('uname').value === '' || 
            document.getElementById('sdescription').value === '' ||
            document.getElementById('email').value === '' || 
            document.getElementById('platf').value === "Select Group" || 
            document.getElementById('cate').value === "Select Category")
        {
            alert("Please fill out all of the starred (*) items" );
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Javascript && operator which returns true if both the elements are true. || operator evaluates to true in case atleast one of the element is true which is what is happening in your case. You can take a look at [Javascript boolean Logic](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/boolean.html)

Comment: The OP wants it to be true if any of the cases are true.  `||` appears to be the right call here

Comment: But using && means it checks to see that they are ALL empty or at the default value. If one of them is filled out and the others still empty would that not allow the form to be submitted?